# Context in a bound node-mysql callback

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I am defining a user object. If the user is logged in they have an ID of more than zero. Then
the conditional calls a node-mysql query and the results are assigned to the object properties. I have binded (bound?) the context in the node-mysql query callback to the "this" of the constructor(I think). My problem is when the user is not logged in and the ID is zero. The context is different. I know this because I copied the property assignments from the "else" part of the conditional into the "if" part and it worked. But I don't want to leave that because it would always query.

```
var Q = require("q");
var mysql = require('mysql');

function User(id, type) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    // If the user is logged in
    if (id > 0) {
        connection.query(query, function(err, results) {
            if(err) {
                deferred.reject(new Error(err))
            } else {
                var result = results[0];

                this.id                 = result.id;
                this.type               = result.type;
                this.nickname           = result.nickname;

                deferred.resolve(this);
            }
        }.bind(this));
    } else {
        this.id                 = 0;
        this.type               = 1;
        this.nickname           = "guest";

        deferred.resolve(this);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The object is instantiated here ... for example. The problem is when a user that is
not logged in (and has an ID of zero) is instantiated the object is empty, but otherwise
contains the properties.

```
var renderIndex = function(req, res) {
    var localId     = req.session.passport.user ? req.session.passport.user : 0,
        options     = {};

    var user = new User(localId, 1);

    return Q.all([
            findGames(),
            user
    ])
    .then (function(allArray) {
        var gamesObj     = allArray[0],
            userObj      = allArray[1];

        options.title           = 'Title';
        options.games           = gamesObj;
        options.user            = userObj;

        // Render the index jade template
        res.render('index', options);
    })
    .done();
};
```

Comment: How are you creating `User` instances?

Comment: var user = new User(localId, 1);

Comment: I still don't understand the issue exactly. Can you show some code where you instantiate and use a `User`, and explain what you expect and what you're getting?

Comment: oops ... forgot that part. It's now updated. I'm exhausted.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, and standalone it seems to work fine.

Comment: OK. Thanks for reviewing it for me. I just recently learned about bind and context and was not sure if I was missing something about binding 'this' to a node-mysql query. I'll dig deeper in another direction.